# WCF DataContractSerializer doesn't pick up contract attributes... why not?

Tags: wcf, datacontractserializer, datacontract, messagecontract

I have the following type which I use as a message contract in WCF:

```
[MessageContract(IsWrapped = true, 
                 WrapperNamespace = "http://example.com/services", 
                 WrapperName = "EchoRequest")]
public class EchoRequest
{
    public EchoRequest() { }
    public EchoRequest(String value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    [MessageBodyMember(Name = "Value", 
                       Namespace = "http://example.com/services", 
                       Order = 0)]
    public String Value { get; set; }
}
```

When I generate a proxy to this type using *svcutil.exe*, I get a client which is able to communicate to a service which hosts it, with the XML namespaces on the elements correct according to the Message Contract attributes.

When I use `Message.CreateMessage(...)` on an instance of it, the namespaces revert to the default (http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/...). When I use an instance of `DataContractSerializer`, the same thing happens. I try to pass a namespace to the `DataContractSerializer` constructor, and only the wrapper gets included in the namespace:

```
var requestMessage = new EchoRequest("hello, world!");
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(EchoRequest), 
                                            "EchoRequest", 
                                            "http://example.com/services");
var stream = new MemoryStream();
serializer.WriteObject(stream, requestMessage);
var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
```

At this, "data" is:

```
<EchoRequest xmlns="http://example.com/services"
             xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestClient"
             xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <a:Value>hello, world!</a:Value>
</EchoRequest>
```

Why does the `DataContractSerializer` appear to ignore the `MessageContract` attributes? How does *svcutil* get this work?

Comment: Thank you for asking this! I just ran into this exact problem and found your question almost immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because message contracts are not data contracts, data contracts use different attributes to mark their classes. Try using a typed message converter;

```
EchoRequest echoRequest = new EchoRequest{ value = "Hello" };

TypedMessageConverter echoMessageConverter = TypedMessageConverter.Create(
                 typeof(echoRequest),
                 "YourActionNameHere",
                 "http://example.com/services");
Message request = echoMessageConverter.ToMessage(
    echoRequest,MessageVersion.Soap11);
```

You'll then have a message all ready to go and can pull the request body out if you need to.

Comment: Yes, this is it! Books and docs appear quite fragmented on how to handle message contracts, and this is the first I've come across TypedMessageConverter. Thanks!

Comment: If the members of your message contracts use XmlSerialization attributes instead of DataContract ones (they could be generated from WSDL/XSD which the DataContractSerializer can't represent), use the overload of `TypedMessageConverter.Create` which accepts an `XmlSerializerFormatAttribute`, to instruct it to use XmlSerialization instead.

Comment: Isnt it easier to make a surrogate class using type of EchoRequest. you can name this class again as EchoRequest and define it as MessageContract in the original one above can be datacontract. It is double definition but it works for me fine.