# Method arguments not matching while implementing WCF service via a console application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding

I am trying to create a basic `WCF application` and am using a `Console Application` to call the service. I add the `service reference` to the `WCF Service` and call it inside the `Console Application` as

```
ServiceName.Service s = new ServiceName.Service();
string str = string.empty;
str = s.GetData(10);  // here i get an argument overload mismatch error
```

inside the `Service.cs` file of the `WCF Service` this method is defined as

```
public string GetData(int value)
{
    return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
}
```

Why am I getting the argument overload mismatch error in this case? I am new to WCF. I have added the WCF service as a  service reference.

Comment: What does intellisense expect that method's arguments to be?

Comment: I guess the wcf client wrapped the in and output parameters in a request/rsponse class. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130032/why-does-wcf-wrap-request-response-types-in-another-xml-element-and-how-to-prev

Comment: what version of Visual Studio and WCF you are using ?

Comment: Its possible that you configured the WCF service to use service contracts?

Comment: I am using VS 2008 . Intellisense gives s.GetData(int value, bool valueSpecified). Yes, i configured the WCF as a service contract.

Comment: Have you modified the GetData method in Service.cs after you added the service reference in the console app?

Comment: No, the GetData has not been modified.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the service wasn't hosted correctly. I rebuilt the solution and it works fine after rehosting the `WCF service client`.

The arguments correspond to the ones defined inside `Service.cs`